# Where to code an array that will be used in both the content and a widget in a Wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, custom-wordpress-pages

I've written some code to develop an array of meta for posts that are in the same category as the current post.  (The code also reorders the list and assigns a key that I can use to append post title strings with 'Step 1', 'Step 2'... , etc.; but that's only relevant to why I need something other than pre-existing Wordpress functions and variables).

I initially put the code in `content.php`, but now I am working on coding a sidebar widget which will use the same data.  It seems like there should be a place to put the code so I don't have to duplicate the code in two places. It also seems like there should be a place to put the code so it only gets executed once when the page loads (In other words, I am aware that I could make the code a function that the content and the widget could each execute; but I believe it's more efficient to execute the code once and then have the content and the widget fetch the array data).

Where should I place the code so that there is only one instance of the code and so that is only gets executed once?

(I'm not aware of how the Wordpress files work with each other.  Is there a place where I can develop and populate a variable so that the content and widget files can simply reference the variable?)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question completely but if you do as follows, it should do the trick in any php code.

In the content or widget `<?php echo function_name(); ?>`

In the functions.php,

```
function function_name() {
global $function_name_output;
if ($function_name_output) return $function_name_output;
//do the work for the $function_name_output
return $function_name_output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wherever array needed:

```
if ( empty($GLOBALS['yourMetaArray']) ) getYourMeta();
# now do stuff with $GLOBALS['yourMetaArray']
```

in functions.php (or alternatively you may be able to include it in same plugin as your widget - see below):

```
function getYourMeta() {
  # whatever
  $GLOBALS['yourMetaArray'] = ......
}
```

I have a plugin which incorporates my equivalent of above identifying visitor country just once. The plugin includes a widget, + filters to enable modification of header etc and shortcodes for use in posts all using same $GLOBALS.